# Visual Studio 2022 silently switches to GNU compiler and refuses to go back to MSVC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

I am attempting to compile this project on GitHub with Visual Studio Community 2022: https://github.com/purpl3F0x/TIDAL-Discord-Rich-Presence-UNOFFICIAL, repository `master`, commit `9b8146e`.

I installed Qt6 through Chocolatey: `choco install -y qt6-base-dev`, which also install MinGW as a dependency (I now have MSVC and a GNU compiler installed).

I clone the project through VS, I edit the .gitignore and remove "CMakeLists.txt" (delete the 2nd line), then I reopen the project, so that VS recognizes it's a CMake project and automatically generates the CMake cache.

Observe, that the CMake Output states the following:

```
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33521.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33521.0
```

I edit my project configuration, by editing the `CMakeSettings.json` (right-click `CMakeLists.txt`, click "CMake Settings", then click "Edit JSON" in the top-right corner) to add an environment variable for Qt6 (add these lines to the debug configuration that VS created for you, under the object in the "configurations" array):

```json
"variables": [
  {
    "name": "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH",
    "value": "C:\\Qt\\6.2.4\\mingw_64",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
],
```

Also add the following, right after the "variables" key, otherwise external Qt6 symbols won't be resolved during build:

```json
"environments": [ { "PATH": "C:\\Qt\\6.2.4\\mingw_64\\bin;${env.PATH}" } ]
```

Attempt to build the project "Build > Build All". You should get the following error (which is expected):

```
C1189   #error:  "Qt requires a C++17 compiler, and a suitable value for __cplusplus. On MSVC, you must pass the /Zc:__cplusplus option to the compiler."   C:\Users\Jonas\Source\Repos\TIDAL-Discord-Rich-Presence-UNOFFICIAL5\out\build\x64-Debug\TIDAL-Discord-Rich-Presence-UNOFFICIAL5 C:\Qt\6.2.4\mingw_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h   94
```

Click "Project > Delete Cache and Reconfigure" to trigger a full CMake generation.

Now (at least for me, at the point of writing this) I get the following partial output:

```
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/c++.exe - skipped
```

It switched to GCC, after I merely changed some CMake settings. This should not happen. VS shouldn't magically switch to another compiler, without me doing anything and especially not without communicating it and by going against the CMake setting for the "Toolset", which is set to `"inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ]`.

---

I found this issue on GitHub, which suggests to set the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` environment variables (not a permanent solution): https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/189.

This does not work either, the compiler check will fail.

After the compiler switches to GCC, I can't find any way to go back to MSVC. The only way that works is to clone the project again and start from the beginning, hoping it won't happen again.

I have tried removing environment variables for MinGW, so that the compiler won't be found, but that only resulted in CMake not finding any compiler at all and failing (?). It doesn't even find MSVC anymore.

This is truly frustrating and I would love to know if someone could give some insights into this problem. I've also had issues debugging, which I now suspect is because it silently switched to GCC.

I was able to reproduce this on my laptop, which had a fresh install of Qt6 via Chocolatey and Visual Studio Community 2022.

---

Edit: Thanks to the comment of Ben Voigt I have tested some more and done the obvious of setting each of the CMakeSettings I mentioned above one by one, and apparently setting "environments" the way I do here causes the MSVC compiler to not be found anymore. That makes finding a solution probably a lot easier, I might be able to answer this post myself.

Edit2: I have installed Qt6 via the installer from https://qt.io. I used the MSVC version and it builds fine, without setting the "environments" key in the `CMakeSettings.json`. Still, adding the above environment by extending the PATH, causes Visual Studio to not use the MSVC compiler. The reason behind this is still unclear to me. But at least I can move forward now.

Comment: In your attempts to go back, did you ever undo your changes to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tested a little more and as per my edit of the original post, adding the "environment" I added above causes this issue. When I removed it, MSVC is found/used again.